# Burning out from stress/pressure of role

Tags: burnout

High turnover in the team means I am now the only Scrum Master.

- Senior Management are hesitant to let me take annual leave, which is understandable.

The trouble is, I am seriously starting to burn out to the point that I am now thinking about changing jobs.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: what is A/l? Annual Leave? btw it's _not_ understandable

Comment: Did your team have more than one Scrum Master in the past? What exactly is burning you out? "One Scrum Master" per team is the normal amount, and being Scrum Master for multiple teams mostly just means each team gets less attention, it should not be causing you stress.

Comment: Yes, Annual leave.

Comment: @Erik when I joined we had 3, 1 left, another is leaving a month from now. I have not had leave for 5 months now, and the work stream I am Scrum Mastering is very fast paced and intense!

Comment: 3 in a single team? Can you add some context to the question about what it is you actually do as a Scrum Master? This sounds like it deviates very far from what's generally a Scrum Master's responsibility, so making it clear to readers what it is you do will probably help generate more relevant answers.

Comment: @Erik I am helping a company turn from Waterfall to agile, so outside of the bog standard  Scrum Master responsibilities, there is a lot to it and is in the lines of agile transformation. I am not going to go into details on here, but it is intense, and challenging. Please don't undermine the role by making it sound like it is stress free, when you are not doing it in my firm which is a FTSE 500 corporate..

Comment: What countr re you in that AL is NEGOTIABLE? In most countries it is a REQUIREMENT.

Comment: @TomTom needs line management approval here.

Comment: I'm not undermining the role, it's just that the question provides zero context on _why_ you are being burned out.

Comment: @bobo2000 And not getting it may be a nice lawsuit following. You ahve no right for a specific date, but mandatory holidays MUST be taken.

Comment: @Erik I just told you, stress and pressure. For the sake of confidentiality, not going to go into details about the politics here, but dealing with people everyday is stressful, especially in highly political environments especially when they are highly opinionated.

Comment: @TomTom mandatory holidays are bank holidays here.

Comment: You need to go speak to your line manager about some annual leave immediately. Depending on your location, they might not necessarily have to give you specific dates that you ask for, but they can't deny it indefinitely. If they don't like the dates you ask for, ask them to give you some dates they'd be happy with. You will at least then be armed with some more information and can decide whether that placates you or you wish to consider a new company.

Answer (score 8):

> Senior Management are hesitant to let me take annual leave, which is understandable.

No, this is not understandable. Senior management have engineered (or at the very least, failed to respond to) a situation which has resulted in you having a bus factor of 1. **This is their fault, not yours** - it is the job of management to be proactive in dealing with this kind of thing.

Therefore what I'd suggest would be:

- Walk into your manager's office and request some leave.
- If your manager says "no", explain how you've been under lots of pressure and are starting to feel burned out.
- If your manager still says "no", start looking for a new job. You can't afford to compromise your health for a job.

If you *do* end up leaving, hopefully your senior management will learn why treating employees like this is a really bad idea.

Comment: My colleague suddenly resigned without warning, leaving me. But yes, they should have hired more Scrum Masters in the event that happened. They didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to talk to your senior management and tell them that they have a choice, do without you for a week or two where you recover, or do without you.

If you think that your job is too stressful, then there are two things you can do: Reduce the stress, or find a job with less stress. That's something you need to talk about; either your management finds ways to reduce the stress, or they'll get into a lot more trouble by losing you altogether.

Remember that working over 40 hours a week is not only bad for you, it is also inefficient because your productivity drops.

One thing that can reduce your stress is just to mentally accept that you will be leaving, maybe not right now, but you will be leaving, and if there is politics going on and people are highly opinionated you just don't give a ****. You know you can leave and leave it all behind you. You know you don't have to care. Do a decent job, and don't care about what people want.

Comment: *working over 40 hours a week is not only bad for you, it is also inefficient because your productivity drops.* -  a Citation for this statement would greatly impropve this answer..

Comment: Funny that you mention about leaving, I am strongly thinking along those lines now. Seriously fed up. I am 1 year into the job, will start searching in 6 months time.